# Is there a way to get debug information from an ajax preflight request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cors

I have some javascript that is making an ajax request using ajax. The preflight OPTIONS call for this request fails. I'd like to display some debug information to the user about the call and it's status code - how can I get this information from the jqXhr object in the error callback?

```
$.ajax
  url: url
  headers: headers
  ...
  error: (jqXhr, status) =>
    # how can I get info about OPTIONS call here?
```

Comment: Have you done a `console.log(jqXhr, status)` and inspected them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**At the moment, this simply isn't possible.**

CORS is severely lacking in error-information when a pre-flight request fails for *whatever* reason, both in the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#cache-and-network-error-steps), and in browser implementations. Relevant excerpts from [HTML5 Rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/):

> If there is an error in the CORS request, the browser will fire the client's `onerror` event handler. It will also print the following error to the console log:
>
> > `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.alice.com. Origin http://api.bob.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.
>
> The browser doesn't give you a lot of details on why the error occurred, it only tells you that something went wrong.

... it goes on to say (under [known issues)](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/#toc-known-bugs):

> No error information provided to `onerror` handler - When the onerror handler is fired, the status code is 0, and there is no statusText. This may be by design, but it can be confusing when trying to debug why CORS requests are failing.

Indeed, all you'll find is that the jqXHR `statusText` property will be blank, the `status` code will be `0`, and `getAllResponseHeaders()` will return an empty string.

Just to be clear: this is a problem getting data out of the underlying `XMLHttpRequest` object. It's not that jQuery is masking information or otherwise not making it available; it simply isn't possible (at the moment) to get error-data out of the `XmlHttpRequest` object in this circumstance.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I guess I'll have to come up with something else!

Comment: @Matt it's been 6 years. Have there been any improvements?

Comment: 9 years later, the sloppy band-aid that is cors is still causing frequent developer headaches.  We need something more efficient & elegant!